# Grails: Mocking of hibernate domain actions - beforeInsert

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

given a domain constellation like this:

```
abstract class A { 
    def myService 
    def beforeInsert() { 
        myService.doIt() 
    } 
} 

class B extends A { 
    def beforeInsert() { 
        super.beforeInsert() 
    } 
}
```

Is it possible to mock the following methods:
- beforeInsert() in B?
- beforeInsert() in A?

Answer (score 1):

For making service method calls optional for unit testing the easiest thing to do is to use null safe method calls:

```
abstract class A { 
    def myService 
    static transients = ['myService']
    def beforeInsert() { 
        myService?.doIt() 
    } 
} 

class B extends A { 
    def beforeInsert() { 
        super.beforeInsert() 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save B objects without flushing in unit tests or
override beforeInsert by metaClass:

```
B.metaClass.beforeInsert = {-> }
```

Comment: Have you tested this? It seems that Grails clobbers any metaClass updates you make.

Comment: Actually to clarify above, it seems that newer versions of Grails use AST transformations to interface with hibernate methods. I'm trying to figure out how to deal with this same problem currently.